# How to populate CollectionView from Dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a view controller which has a textField on it. When a user presses the textField, it segues to a tableView and populates the tableView with the `"name"` from my dictionary.

My dictionary data is as below:

```
var objects = [
{
    "id": "001",
    "typeTwo": "Poison",
    "name": "Bulbasaur",
    "type": "Grass"
},
{
    "id": "002",
    "typeTwo": "Poison",
    "name": "Ivysaur",
    "type": "Grass"
}]
```

... and so on.

When the user selects a cell, it passes the name back to the first VC and shows the pokemon image for what they selected.

This all works fine.

The user can then press a button which segues to a `CollectionViewController` and you can see all the Pokemon shown.

**What I'd like to then do:**

Currently, I just have the CollectionView set up to just display all the Pokemon using the same dictionary data above, but What I'd like, is for it to only show the Pokemon that have the same `"Type"`

**For example:**

If the user selected `"Bulbasaur"`, which has types of Grass and Poison, then when they go to the CollectionView, it would only show the Pokemon that are either Grass or Poison as well.

Hopefully, that makes sense, please let me know if you need to see any of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filtering to filter dictionary to return only elements that match criteria you write in predicate which here is getting pokemons having a specific type :

```
var objects = [
    [
        "id": "001",
        "typeTwo": "Poison",
        "name": "Bulbasaur",
        "type": "Grass"
    ],
    [
        "id": "002",
        "typeTwo": "Fly",
        "name": "Ivysaur",
        "type": "Grass"
    ],
    [
        "id": "003",
        "typeTwo": "Poison",
        "name": "Ivysaur",
        "type": "Water"
    ]
]

var filteredObjects = objects.filter{

    let valueType = $0["type"]
    let valueTypeTwo = $0["typeTwo"]

    if (valueType == "Grass" || valueType == "Water") && valueTypeTwo == "Poison"
    {
        return true
    }

    return false
}


print(filteredObjects)
```

Comment: So that did filter my results in the CollectionView, but it's didn't do it properly. It just filtered by the number of Pokemon with the type Grass, so it simply displayed the first 14 Pokemon in the list, rather that the actual Pokemon itself, which was of type Grass. Does that make sense? I'm assuming it's because I'm not using an indexPath?

Comment: Yes you should show from filteredObjects not objects itself or add code for showing in collectionView

Comment: Ah yes, didn't change that in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` function. Works now. The only other thing I need help with is also checking it for `"typeTwo"` in the dictionary. As Grass does appear in `"typeTwo"`, so these Pokemon are not shown currently, as we are only filtering by `"type"` - Is there a way to filter by both `"type"` and `"typeTwo"` ? Thanks

Comment: var filteredObjects = objects.filter{ $0["type"] == "Grass" &&  $0["typeTwo"] == "Poison" }

Comment: Thanks. I did try that, but it doesn't work. It gives error: `Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions` - Any thoughts?

Comment: this should solve this var filteredObjects = objects.filter{ ($0["type"] == "Grass") }.filter{ ($0["typeTwo"] == "Poison")  }

Comment: Yep that seems to be accepted as an expression,  Thanks! One last quick question though please - This expression only filters it if a Pokemon has: `["type"] == "Grass"` AND `["typeTwo"] == "Poison"`. Is there an expression that can do: `["type"] == "Grass"` OR `["typeTwo"] == "Grass"` - So it can either check one or the other and not have to match both to a Pokemon? Thanks so much

Comment: I have edited the answer & now you can modify the if statement to whatever you want, Please mark it as correct if it was helpful :)

Comment: Hi, I have posted another question relating to a similar issue as what you helped me with here. If you wouldn't mind, would you take a look to see if you can help? Thanks so much - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38798075/how-to-filter-a-dictionary-and-output-result-into-collectionviewcontroller-in-sw

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a dictionary as the model for a collection view. Dictionaries are unordered collections, and collection views show ordered lists of objects.

The data structure you've shown is an array of dictionaries. That's a perfectly valid way to store the data for a collection view since an array **is** an ordered collection.

Mohamed's code to filter your dictionary is a good way to filter your results, but you then need to use that new filtered array as the model (data) for your collection view.