# How to filter a dictionary and output result into CollectionViewController in swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, uicollectionview

I am making an app that shows Pokemon and their types. Also part of the app will show their weaknesses.

I have a global variable that lists all the Pokemon, which looks as follows:

```
var objects = [
{
"id": "001",
"typeTwo": "Poison",
"name": "Bulbasaur",
"type": "Grass"
},
{
"id": "002",
"typeTwo": "Poison",
"name": "Ivysaur",
"type": "Grass"
},
{
"id": "025",
"typeTwo": "",
"name": "Pikachu",
"type": "Electric"
}]
```

etc...

When the user selects a Pokemon from the 1st VC, they then press a button and it passes the object of that Pokemon to my `CollectionViewController` - and stores this in `var selectedPokemonObject = [String:String]()`

I have my `CollectionViewController` set up to then filter my Pokemon objects and display only Pokemon that match the type of Pokemon that the user selected. For example:

The user selects: **Pikachu** (type `"Electric"`)

The user then goes to the `CollectionViewController` and all Pokemon of type `"Electric"` are shown. Some of my code for that is:

```
var filteredObjects = [[String:String]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

    filteredObjects = objects.filter{

        let valueType = $0["type"]
        let valueTypeTwo = $0["typeTwo"]

        if (valueType == selectedPokemonObject["type"] || valueType == selectedPokemonObject["typeTwo"]) && (valueTypeTwo == selectedPokemonObject["typeTwo"] || valueTypeTwo == selectedPokemonObject["type"])
        {

            return true
        }

        return false
    }
}
```

I then set the cell info in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` as follows:

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    let object = filteredObjects[indexPath.row]

    cell.pokemonName.text = object["name"]!
    cell.pokemonImage.image = UIImage(named: "\(object["id"]!)"+"\(object["name"]!)"+"_small")

    return cell

}
```

All of this works.

**What I'd like to happen**

Instead of the `CollectionViewController` showing Pokemon of the same type as the one the user selected, I'd like it to show Pokemon that has a Type that I define. For example:

The user selects: **Pikachu** (`"type": "Electric"`)

The user then goes to the `CollectionViewController` and all Pokemon of type `"Ground"` are shown. Or, a more complex case:

The user selects: **Bulbasaur** (`"type": "Grass"` and `"typeTwo": "Poison"`)

The user then goes to the `CollectionViewController` and all Pokemon of type `"Fire"`, `"Ice"`, `"Flying"` and `"Psychic"` are shown.

I'm really having trouble to figure this out, so any help is appreciated. I have looked at Switch statements but not sure if this is the right approach? Thanks

Comment: If the pokemon has a single type, is the "typeTwo" field nil?

Comment: @HaydenHolligan `"typeTwo"` then is just a blank `String` - I've amended my question at the top to show a Pokemon that has only 1 type so you can see. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

My preferred approach would be to initially setup a Dictionary containing the Pokemon that are weak to each type. I would do this so you can get the list of weak Pokemon without looping through the entire list of Pokemon (O(1) time instead of O(N) if you know big-O notation).

In a separate Swift command-line project,

```
//Assuming objects is setup similar to below
var objects = [
    ["id": "001",
        "typeTwo": "Poison",
        "name": "Bulbasaur",
        "type": "Grass"],
    ["id": "002",
        "typeTwo": "Poison",
        "name": "Ivysaur",
        "type": "Grass"],
    ["id": "025",
        "typeTwo": "",
        "name": "Pikachu",
        "type": "Electric"]]

var pokemonTypeDefenseChart = [String: [String]]()
pokemonTypeDefenseChart["Grass"] = ["Fire", "Ice", "Flying"]
pokemonTypeDefenseChart["Poison"] = ["Psychic", "Ground"]
pokemonTypeDefenseChart["Electric"] = ["Ground"]
// Setup rest of the weaknesses (this part is manual unfortunately)

var pokemonWeaknessChart = [String: [String]]()

func getWeaknesses(type: String, name: String) {
    for weakness in pokemonTypeDefenseChart[type]! {
        if pokemonWeaknessChart[weakness] == nil {
            pokemonWeaknessChart[weakness] = []
        }
        pokemonWeaknessChart[weakness]?.append(name)
    }
}

for object in objects {
    if let type = object["type"] where !type.isEmpty, let name = object["name"] {
        getWeaknesses(type, name: name)
    }

    if let typeTwo = object["typeTwo"] where !typeTwo.isEmpty, let name = object["name"] {
        getWeaknesses(typeTwo, name: name)
    }
}

print(pokemonWeaknessChart)
```

This code *should* output the entire list of Pokemon weaknesses. You can directly copy that output into your project as a new variable (probably stored where your `objects` are stored).

So now, if you select a Pokemon, this below code will return the full list of Pokemon weak to `valueType` and `valueTypeTwo`.

```
let valueType = "Fire"
let valueTypeTwo = "Electric"

var pokemonWeaknesses = pokemonWeaknessChart[valueType]
if !valueTypeTwo.isEmpty, let pokemonTypeTwoWeaknesses = pokemonWeaknessChart[valueTypeTwo] {
    pokemonWeaknesses?.appendContentsOf(pokemonTypeTwoWeaknesses)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm struggling to see how this fits into my code already. Could you break it down a little more and explain where I need to place my code? thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that to add the part where you actually get the Pokemon that are super effective. I will update my answer, however, I think it will be best performance-wise if you create a dictionary with either "strong" or "weak" for the key, and a dictionary for the value. The inner dictionary would the Pokemon type for the key. this way you can get the list of pokemon that are either strong or weak against a given type in near-instant time. Otherwise you will need to loop through the entire pokedex each time you want to find weaknesses.

Comment: This is getting a little complex, so I will update my answer when I get home tonight

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! Look forward to seeing your answer

Comment: I swear I have not forgotten! I started watching Stranger Things last night and today I need to ask SO a question myself, getting into some weird swifty things...

Comment: Updated the entire question. Let me know if it makes sense and/or if you have issues. I'm preeeeetty sure this will do what you want.